# Problems in uploading files with django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-views

I'm new using django. I've to upload a file and fot this I'm following the instructions present in official documentation:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs

my index.htlm

```
    <form action="upload_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="upfile" size="30">
        <input type="submit" name="upfile" value= " Upload ">
    </form>
```

my views.py:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('/my_path_to_tmp/tmp_files/input_file', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
    if ( f.file_name.endswith("sdf") ):
        return "sdf"
    elif ( f.file_name.endswith("smi") ):
        return "smi"

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file_type = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['upfile'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('calculate', file_type)
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    (r'^upload_file$', 'upload_file'),   
    (r'calculate/$', 'calculation'),
)
```

Really I don't know what I'm doing wrong here but it seems that the condition

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

in views.py fails. Even if the method="POST" to the html form.
Anybody has an idea?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your form action is correct?

Shouldn't it be something like this instead:

```
<form action="{% url upload_file %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. I have no experience with django. If I try to do as you say I obtain the following error: TemplateSyntaxError: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'upload_file' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Yeah, that's just because your url file should look like:
`urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    (r'^upload_file$', 'upload_file' name='upload_file'),   
    (r'calculate/$', 'calculation', name='calculation'),
)`

Comment: OK, thanks. If I modify as fylb says I obtain a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in urls.py file on "name="

Comment: @green69: Instead of `name='calculation'` use `'calculation'`, and same for the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps output the request.method at the beginning of your method, just to be sure... after that, print form._errors.

Comment: Thanks to help me fyib. Actually it seems that request.method == "POST" but request.POST is empty. How is that possible?