# image uploading using django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, error-handling

i have an code, code is running well, problem with this code is that it did not get the filename when the file is uploaded.

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
        if 'filename' in request.FILES:
            filename = request.FILES['filename']
        else:
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_profileform/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return render_to_response('user_profile.html', {'form': form })

def handle_uploaded_file(f):

    destination = open('media/name', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks(): 
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

my form is :-

```
<form action="/user_profileform/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uform" id="userform">{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="usubmit">
</form>
```

when using this the file is uploaded properly but  did not get the file name,, why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems in uploading files with django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192038/problems-in-uploading-files-with-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably that you are trying to read the filename from the `request.FILES` dictionary. This dictionary contains an `UploadedFile` object for each file upload field in your form. The filename is a property of that `UploadedFile` object. Try this:

```
if request.FILES['file'].name:
    filename = request.FILES['file'].name
```

If that doesn't work, show us your actual form and the code where you are trying to use the filename.